# how would I change the font color of the Windows 7 taskbar? with aero

Tags: windows-7, fonts, taskbar, colors

I'm running Aero but it's next to impossible to read the task bar icon titles:

[image: pic]

How would I change the font color to a different color (i.e black) so it's visible and makes the background and task bar look nice?

Answer (score 0):

can't find a way to change the color - here's how you can change the backgroudn which the text is on until someone gets you the right answer...

Control Panel > Display > Select a theme > Click color at the bottom  > Create your own color and make it darker than the one that's selected.

You might find a different theme that's easier to see by searching for new ones online. There's high-contrast available but that would be white on a black background and IMO that is harder to read.

Comment: alright, thanks. i managed to find an identical wallpaper but in black. I also switched to "Placebo black market 2" (a theme) and it works perfect and looks neat.